# When will the next version of Ubuntu be released for a better user experience?

Tags: system

When can we expect the next version of Ubuntu to be released, promising an enhanced user experience?

Comment: "enhanced user experience" is subjective, and effectively makes this post simply "spam" or "junk".  Ubuntu releases every 6 months, once in April and once in October.  LTSes are released every two years (so 24.04 is the next LTS).  There is no other answers that're valid.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pros and Cons of LTS Vs. Normal Release](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60868/pros-and-cons-of-lts-vs-normal-release)

Comment: "Enhanced user experience" seems too broad to me. You should [edit] your question and specify the most important thing you are expecting.

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu is released by Canonical twice per year in April and October. The release date is typically in the 2nd half of the month.

The release schedule for the next version is made public after a version is released. Some of the software updates are mentioned there, but not necessarily all development goals.

The release schedule of the next Ubuntu release Ubuntu 24.04 LTS "Noble Numbat" [can be found here](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/noble-numbat-release-schedule/35649)